# Install Cx Freeze with Anaconda 4.3.1

Tags: python, installation, anaconda, cx-freeze

I would like to install Cx Freeze (in order to compile .exe file with Anaconda 4.3.1) but I don't manage to do it.

I downloaded the whl and the .tar.gz files from https://pypi.python.org/pypi/cx_Freeze/5.0.2 but I don't know how to run it and I don't know if it is compatible with Anaconda...

I tried : conda install -c pyzo cx_freeze=4.3.3

But I have the following error message  :

> > > File "< stdin>", line 1
> > >           conda install -c pyzo cx_freeze=4.3.3
> > >                       ^
> > >       SyntaxError: invalid syntax

I also tried : conda install pip

But I have the following error message :

> > > File "< stdin>", line 1
> > >           conda install pip
> > >                       ^
> > >       SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Would you please kindly help me ?

Thank you in advance

Comment: use pip install instead. Open command prompt and cd C:\Python27\Scripts (use the location your anaconda 4.3.1 scripts are located) the type pip install cx_freeze

Comment: Thank you for your answer but when I type "pip install cx_freeze", I get... :

  File "<stdin>", line 1
    pip install cx_freeze
              ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: Are you on windows? Did you make sure pip is in the directory you're running pip install from? There needs to be a pip.exe there